# unable to install samba on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, samba

Trying to install samba and get this error

```
anil@anil:~$ sudo apt-get  install  samba 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 samba : Depends: samba-common (= 2:4.1.6+dfsg-1ubuntu2.14.04.4) but 2:4.1.6+dfsg-1ubuntu2.14.04.8 is to be installed
         Depends: samba-common-bin (= 2:4.1.6+dfsg-1ubuntu2.14.04.4) but 2:4.1.6+dfsg-1ubuntu2.14.04.8 is to be installed
         Depends: samba-dsdb-modules but it is not going to be installed
         Depends: samba-libs (= 2:4.1.6+dfsg-1ubuntu2.14.04.4) but 2:4.1.6+dfsg-1ubuntu2.14.04.8 is to be installed
         Recommends: samba-vfs-modules but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First run these commands in terminal (press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>):

- `sudo apt-get --fix-broken install`
- `sudo apt-get clean`
- `sudo apt-get autoclean`
- `sudo apt-get autoremove`
- `sudo dpkg --configure -a`
- `sudo apt-get update` then following

1.Changed software and updates to main server

2.unmarked all "other software" sources

[image: ims]

3.reload it and run for software update.

4.Install samba : `sudo apt-get  install  samba`

Comment: `sudo apt-get --fix-broken-install` gives me the message: `E: Command line option --fix-broken-install is not understood`. I'm on 14.04.

Comment: @Dai, you typed `--fix-broken-install`, so you have an extra `-`. You actually need to type `--fix-broken install`.

Answer (score 3):

run command

```
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo apt-get install samba
```

it will install broken dependencies.if problem not resolved  then use  [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa) where good explaination of resolving it .