# Problem installing dolphin emulator?

Tags: 14.04, libraries

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit  on my Laptop.
I'm trying to install dolphin emulator on my system 
Here is the terminal output.

```
Selecting previously unselected package dolphin-emu.
(Reading database ... 205709 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack /home/tbh/Downloads/de.deb ...
Unpacking dolphin-emu (4.0) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of dolphin-emu:
 dolphin-emu depends on libavcodec53 (>= 6:0.8.3-1~) | libavcodec-extra-53 (>= 6:0.8.6); however:
Package libavcodec53 is not installed.
Package libavcodec-extra-53 is not installed.
dolphin-emu depends on libavformat53 (>= 6:0.8.3-1~) | libavformat-extra-53 (>= 6:0.8.6); however:
Package libavformat53 is not installed.
Package libavformat-extra-53 is not installed.
dolphin-emu depends on libavutil51 (>= 6:0.8.3-1~) | libavutil-extra-51 (>= 6:0.8.6); however:
Package libavutil51 is not installed.
Package libavutil-extra-51 is not installed.
dolphin-emu depends on libglew1.8 (>= 1.8.0); however:
Package libglew1.8 is not installed.
dpkg: error processing package dolphin-emu (--install):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.1+14.04.20140409-    0ubuntu1+elementary2~ubuntu14.04.1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.10.1-0ubuntu2) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.54ubuntu1.1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
dolphin-emu
```

Comment: refer my answer @Mohamad [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/661216/unable-to-install-samba-on-ubuntu-14-04)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried updating your system by doing `sudo apt-get update`? If you haven't, I'd highly recommend doing that before proceeding to install the .deb file.

From the looks of it, you are missing some files. Hopefully doing `sudo apt-get update` works for you. If not, I'd highly recommend proceeding to do the following below. This option is a fail proof option of getting Dolphin installed.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:dolphin-emu/gcc-for-dolphin
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:dolphin-emu/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install dolphin-emu
```

The following repository `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:dolphin-emu/gcc-for-dolphin` needs libstdc++6 (>=4.9) in order to be run **dolphin-emu** on 12.04 and 14.04.

Comment: I did it by adding the sources then by
       sudo apt-get install dolphin-emu

Comment: Glad to see you got it resolved.